# How to RDP into remote Hyper-V Ubuntu VM that uses xRDP?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have the special xRDP version of Ubuntu installed in Hyper-V and can successfully use Enhanced session.

I setup the VM to use an External NIC that's bridged in Windows so it can get an IP from my local network just like the host Windows install.

From another Windows machine, how can I remote into that VM using Remote Desktop Connection?